# How to add a TableRow to TableLayout without making changes to other Rows

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I have a table layout with 3 columns and i need to have the last row with one column and when I add it the form of the other columns change
[image]

I want the column "NIVEAU" to be in the middle

> here is the code :

```
View v = new View(contentView.getContext());
        v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                2
        ));
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        t1 = (TableLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.main_table);

        TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(contentView.getContext());
        tr_head.setId(10);
        tr_head.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        tr_head.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView label_matiere = new TextView(contentView.getContext());
        label_matiere.setId(20);
        label_matiere.setText("MATIERE");
        label_matiere.setMaxWidth(70);
        label_matiere.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        label_matiere.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr_head.addView(label_matiere);// add the column to the table row here

        TextView label_niveau = new TextView(contentView.getContext());
        label_niveau.setId(21);
        label_niveau.setText("NIVEAU"); 
        label_niveau.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
        label_niveau.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr_head.addView(label_niveau); 

        TextView label_prix = new TextView(contentView.getContext());
        label_prix.setId(22);
        label_prix.setText("PRIX(DH)"); 
        label_prix.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
        label_prix.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); 
        tr_head.addView(label_prix);     

        t1.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        t1.addView(v);


        Integer count=0;

        while (count<=7) {
            String Matiere = "matiere :"+count;
            String niveau = "niveau :"+count;
            Integer Prix = count+120;


            TableRow tr = new TableRow(contentView.getContext());
            tr.setId(100+count);
            tr.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



  TextView labelmatiere = new TextView(contentView.getContext());
            labelmatiere.setId(200+count);
            labelmatiere.setText(Matiere);
            labelmatiere.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            tr.addView(labelmatiere);
  TextView labelniveau = new TextView(contentView.getContext());
            labelniveau.setId(200+count);
            labelniveau.setText(niveau);
            tr.addView(labelniveau);
  TextView labelprix = new TextView(contentView.getContext());
            labelprix.setId(200+count);
            labelprix.setText(Prix.toString());
            tr.addView(labelprix);


            t1.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            View l = new View(contentView.getContext());
            l.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    1
            ));
            l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            t1.addView(l);
            count++;
        }
        TableRow add = new TableRow(contentView.getContext());
        add.setId(100+count);
        add.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        add.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView addMatiere = new TextView(contentView.getContext());
        addMatiere.setId(200+count);
        addMatiere.setText("+Ajouter une nouvelle matiere");
        addMatiere.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        addMatiere.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        add.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        add.addView(addMatiere);

        t1.addView(add, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

please there is any solution to this problem 
can I add the last Row just like a TextView but without changing the look ?

Comment: At first glance, I would suggest using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` instead. It is more flexible.

Comment: So there is no solution for this ?

Comment: I am saying that your solution is fragile and requires a great deal of maintenance. Using  a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` will give you more flexibility when you expand your list or add values to it. It is Layout based which gives you more control over the visual appearance and you can easily add headers and footers to it.

Comment: ok, thank you so much i get you .. i will use the `RecyclerView` thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I resolved this problem by adding span programmatically like this :

```
TextView addMatiere = new TextView(contentView.getContext());
        addMatiere.setId(200+count);
        addMatiere.setText("+Ajouter une nouvelle matiere");
        addMatiere.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        addMatiere.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
        addMatiere.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        add.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        add.addView(addMatiere);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) addMatiere.getLayoutParams();
        params.span=3; //amount of columns you will span
        addMatiere.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and as #Barns said using `RecyclerView` or `ListView` is better than `TbaleLayout`